# How to use glossary entry in siunitx command?

Tags: glossaries, siunitx

I am using glossaries for the list of symbols in my document and I added some keys for units. I want to use the unit(s) defined in the glossary in a siunitx range. This works fine when my defined unit is only one term but fails for more complex ones. Is there some way to achieve this?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[symbols,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

% add unit
\glsaddkey
{unit}
{}
{\glsentryunit}
{\Glsentryunit}
{\glsunit}
{\Glsunit}
{\GLSunit}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

% add unit
\glsaddkey
{unit2}
{}
{\glsentryunit2}
{\Glsentryunit2}
{\glsunit2}
{\Glsunit2}
{\GLSunit2}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit2}

\makeglossaries

\glsxtrnewsymbol[%
description=power,%
unit=\si{\W},%
unit2=\si{\J\per\s}
]{P}{P}

\begin{document}

\glsunit{P}, \glsunit2{P}\\

\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\glsunit{P}}\\

\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\glsunit2{P}}

\end{document}
```

[image: As you can see in the 3rd line the units are not shown.]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two problems here. The first is that you can't have command names that include digits, so `\glsentryunit2` actually means `\glsentryunit` followed by `2`. (This is why there are commands, such as `\glsentryuseri`, that contain Roman numerals instead of digits.)

Your first `\glsaddkey` command defines `\glsentryunit`, and your second `\glsaddkey` attempts to define `\glsentryunit` but that command has already been defined, so you get an error. To get around this, you need to find another name, for example `\glsentryunitII`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[symbols,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

% add unit
\glsaddkey
{unit}
{}
{\glsentryunit}
{\Glsentryunit}
{\glsunit}
{\Glsunit}
{\GLSunit}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

% add unit
\glsaddkey
{unit2}
{}
{\glsentryunitII}
{\GlsentryunitII}
{\glsunitII}
{\GlsunitII}
{\GLSunitII}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit2}

\makeglossaries

\glsxtrnewsymbol[%
description=power,%
unit=\si{\W},%
unit2=\si{\J\per\s}
]{P}{P}

\begin{document}

\glsunit{P}, \glsunitII{P}\\

\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\glsunit{P}}\\

\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\glsunitII{P}}

\end{document}
```

The second problem is that

```
\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\glsunitII{P}}
```

doesn't work, but neither does

```
\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\si{\J\per\s}}
```

It needs to be

```
\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\J\per\s}
```

I recommend removing the `\si` part from the definition and providing convenient commands that add it where needed. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}
\usepackage[symbols,xindy]{glossaries-extra}

% add unit
\glsaddkey
{unit}
{}
{\glsentryunit}
{\Glsentryunit}
{\glsunit}
{\Glsunit}
{\GLSunit}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit}

% add unit
\glsaddkey
{unit2}
{}
{\glsentryunitII}
{\GlsentryunitII}
{\glsunitII}
{\GlsunitII}
{\GLSunitII}

\glssetnoexpandfield{unit2}

\makeglossaries

\glsxtrnewsymbol[%
description=power,%
unit=\W,%
unit2=\J\per\s
]{P}{P}

\newcommand{\sigls}[2][]{\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{\si{\glsentryunit{#2}}}}

\newcommand{\siglsII}[2][]{\glsdisp[#1]{#2}{\si{\glsentryunitII{#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\sigls{P}, \siglsII{P}

\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\glsentryunit{P}}

\SIrange{0.5}{2}{\glsentryunitII{P}}

\end{document}
```

[image: image of result]

*Edit:*

In the above, the range doesn't index the entry. If you want it indexed, you can add `\glsadd`. Convenient commands:

```
\newcommand*{\siglsrange}[4][]{\SIrange[#1]{#2}{#3}{\glsentryunit{#4}}\glsadd{#4}}
\newcommand*{\siglsrangeII}[4][]{\SIrange[#1]{#2}{#3}{\glsentryunitII{#4}}\glsadd{#4}}
```

Usage:

```
\siglsrange{0.5}{2}{P}
\siglsrangeII{0.5}{2}{P}
```