# glossaries in pgfplot not displayed

Tags: pgfplots, glossaries, glossaries-extra, externalize

I am currently trying to use a glossary entry in the labels of a PGFPlot. 
E.g. `ylabel={$\gls{F}_h\ in\ \glsunit{F}}`.

I set up glsunit according to [How to use glossary entry in siunitx command?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/321022/how-to-use-glossary-entry-in-siunitx-command). Inside text this is working fine, just not in the PGFPlot. There the symbols only appear as `???`.

Further info: I am using tikz externalize for the plots and use a bib file and bib2gls for the symbols.

Is there a way to resolve the symbols inside the PGFPlot?

the stripped down example:

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{symbols.bib}
@entry{F,
    name={\ensuremath{F}},
    description={Force},
    unit={\si{\newton}}
    }

@entry{s,
    name={\ensuremath{s}},
    description={Normalised Distance},
    unit={}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=black, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[record, abbreviations, nonumberlist]{glossaries-extra}
    \setabbreviationstyle{long-short}
    \newglossary[slg]{symbols}{syi}{syg}{Symbols}
    \glsaddkey{unit}{\glsentrytext{\glslabel}}{\glsentryunit}{\GLsentryunit}{\glsunit}{\Glsunit}{\GLSunit}
    \glssetnoexpandfield{unit}
    \newglossarystyle{symbunitlong}{%
        \setglossarystyle{long3col}% base this style on the list style
        \renewenvironment{theglossary}{% Change the table type --> 3 columns
          \begin{longtable}{lp{\glsdescwidth}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm}}}%
          {\end{longtable}}%
        %
        \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%  Change the table header
          \bfseries Sign & \bfseries Description & \bfseries Unit \\
          \hline
          \endhead%
        }
        \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%  Change the displayed items
            \glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}} %
            & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
            & \glsunit{##1}  \tabularnewline
        }
    }
    \GlsXtrLoadResources[src={symbols}, type={symbols}]
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{external}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
%    \tikzexternalize[
%        mode=list and make,
%%        force remake,
%    ]
\begin{document}
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols, style=symbunitlong]
    Just a test with \gls{s} and \gls{F} in \glsunit{F}. \\
    %
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xlabel={\gls{s}},
            ylabel={$\gls{F}\ in\ \glsunit{F}$},
        ]
            \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
                (2,-2.8559703)
                (3,-3.5301677)
                (4,-4.3050655)
                (5,-5.1413136)
                (6,-6.0322865)
                (7,-6.9675052)
                (8,-7.9377747)
            };
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you don't do this there is a lot of work for us (the helpers) and also maybe a lot of guessing what you do. From what you have stated so far I would guess that you have to use `/tikz/external/mode=list and make` to make it work. See the [tikz manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=678) or [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=539) for details.

Comment: I added a stripped down version of my problem

Comment: /tikz/external/mode = list and make did not resolve the problem. Still only ??? is displayed

Comment: I just adjusted your MWE and removed unnecessary stuff. But also when I compile this one I **everywhere** just get `??`, not only in the `tikzpicture` or `axis` environment. Please modify it again and/or describe in comments or the normal text *what to do* so that at least the stuff outside `tikzpicture` shows up.

Comment: first of all thank you for editing it. It seems I removed one line too much. Added \printunsrtglossary[type=symbols, style=symbunitlong] after begin document. Now it works without the externalize. But not with externalize

Comment: Since you didn't state something else I assume that one just has to run LaTeX (several times). But unfortunately then I (still) just receive `??`s and nothing in "Symbols" section ...

Comment: did you run bib2gls filename in between?

Comment: I can confirm that running latex, bib2gls and latex again shows the glossaries stuff everywhere when the `external` library isn't used and it doesn't work in the `axis` environment when the `external` library *is* used. Unfortunately I don't know why. Maybe @NicolaTalbot has an idea why !?!?